# awk - checking timecode

Tags: bash, shell, awk, timecodes

In my file, every line look something like this:

```
\18:49:25 1920/11/29\ 0.25
```

Is there a way how can I check that the timecode is correct that there are no typos in it (eq. max 12 months, year written in 4 numbers, etc.), when I have this saved in variable?

```
\%H:%M:%S %Y/%m/%d\
```

Thanks

P.S. I know that the checking can't work everytime (I can't distinguish minutes from seconds, but i can check that I don't have 13 months etc. )

EDIT:
The timecode is not fixed. The data file can look like this:

```
    *1920.11.29 18.49.25* 0.25
```

but it also may look completly different. The only sure think is that I have the timecode saved in general form in variable. In this case it would be

```
*%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S*
```

**EDIT2:**
It looks like I did not express myself clear, so here are some examples what I want to achieve:

*1)*

```
$ cat input.txt
29/11/1920 17:50
30/11/1920 18:20
01/12/1920 07:20
...

$ ./checktimecode "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" input.txt
```

Result= timecode OK

*2)*

```
$ cat input.txt
**1920/11@17:50**
**1920/12@18:20**
**1920/13@07:20**
...

$ ./checktimecode "**%Y/%d@%H:%M**" input.txt
```

Result= timecode OK

```
$ ./checktimecode "**%Y/%m@%H:%M**" input.txt
```

Result= BAD timecode

*3)*

```
$ cat input.txt
!17/50/20\29/11/1920&
!18/20/50\30/11/1920&
!07/18/05\01/12/1920&
...

$ ./checktimecode "!%H/%M/%S\%d/%m/%Y&" input.txt
```

Result= timecode OK

```
$ ./checktimecode "%H/%M/%S\%d/%m/%Y&" input.txt
```

Result= BAD timecode

Comment: Strange that you think you can't distinguish minutes and seconds, but you're sure you won't get months and days mixed up, given that there are various ordering conventions for writing the fields of a date, but time is quite uniform: hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/10085538/check-if-given-strftime-format-matches-a-date, no desired answers though. Looks like using external language like c/python is the best way to approach this. viva SKJ

Answer (score 1):

#### sample date:

```
$ cat input.txt

\18:00:00 1920/11/29\ OK
\18:00:00 1920/13/29\ KO
\00:61:00 1920/02/29\ KO
\25:00:00 1920/11/29\ KO
\00:00:00 1920/11/29\ OK
```

#### `awk` script

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{
    FS = "\\"
}

!check_date_time($2)

function check_date_time(dt,     a,date,time,year,mon,day,hour,min,sec)
{
    split(dt, a, " ")
    date = a[2]
    time = a[1]

    split(date, a, "/")
    year = a[1]
    mon  = a[2]
    day  = a[3]

    split(time, a, ":")
    hour = a[1]
    min  = a[2]
    sec  = a[3]

    return check_date(year, mon, day) && check_time(hour, min, sec)
}

function check_time(hour, min, sec)
{
    return 0<=hour && hour<=23 && 0<=min && min<=59 && 0<=sec && sec<=59
}

function check_date(year, mon, day)
{
    if (mon < 0 || mon >= 13)
        return 0
    else if (day == 31 && (mon == 4 ||  mon == 6 || mon == 9 || mon == 11))
        return 0;
    else if (day >= 30 && mon == 2)
        return 0;
    else if (mon == 2 && day == 29 && ! (  year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)))
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

#### output

```
$ awk -f chk_date_time.awk input.txt

\18:00:00 1920/13/29\ KO
\00:61:00 1920/02/29\ KO
\25:00:00 1920/11/29\ KO
```

Comment: I am sorry, I apparantly didn't express clearly what I want to achieve, I updated the question with examples. I am not limited with only 2 formats of the file, there are basicaly infinite combinations of timecodes.

Comment: @user1290065. You need split the task into two steps: (1) transform date-string to a unified-format. (2) do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's [`time.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime) or [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
from datetime import datetime
import sys
format = sys.argv[1]
file = sys.argv[2]

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            datetime.strptime(line.rstrip(), format)
        except:
            print "BAD timecode"
            sys.exit(1)

print "timecode OK"
```

**Edit:**

Usage:

```
$ ./checktimecode "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" input.txt
```

Comment: This looks really simple, thanks for solution with Python. But if possible, I would really love to have a solution using bash

Comment: @user1290065: AWK is a programming language, as is Python. When you say you want a solution in Bash, do you mean in the shell language? Because AWK is no more "Bash" than Python is. By the way, [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html#Date-Parsing) also has a `strptime` function. Also, the `time` library in Linux has [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime), so you could easily write this in C. Ultimately, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: Note that some versions of `date` such as that for [OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html) use `strptime` to accept format strings for input parsing. It may be possible to use that in a shell script to do what you want, but it will be less portable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in shell. And why reinvent the wheel? Because this is a part of my assignment which I am supposed to write using only standart shell functions and this is the last part of the script I can't figure out.

Comment: @user1290065: The other answers provide some hints, but you will have to add some additional code to handle the general case of parsing and processing arbitrary format codes. Look at the [source for `strptime`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=time/strptime_l.c;h=7bc5ed3eb0a349ce287813d319ef88753571ef4e;hb=HEAD) to see the complexity you would need to re-implement. Unfortunately, if a command-line `strptime` is available, it's not common.

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the H, M, S, Y, m and d to whatever rules you want...

```
awk -F'[\\\\:/ ]' '{H=$2; M=$3; S=$4; Y=$5; m=$6; d=$7; print "=" H "=" M "=" S "=" Y "=" m "=" d "="}'
```

Comment: But I don't know how the timecode look, it can look completely different. But no matter how it looks, I will have it stored with % instead of numbers in some variable. Or I don't understand your example properly.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Are you saying that even the format is not fixed?

Comment: The file may also look like this for example:
\1920/11/29 18:49:25\ 0.25

But I don't know that. The only think I know, is that, in this case, I will have in my variable this:
\%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S\

And now I want to check, if the data file is in correct format and there are no typos in it, eq. max 12 months, year written in 4 numbers, etc..

Is it clearer now?

Comment: So how do you expect program to figure it out? How would you do it manually? You have to define some logic for the program to work on.

Comment: Please take a look at the question, I added some examples. I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@(do (defvar counter (range 1)))
@(collect :vars ())
@  (bind lineno @(pop counter))
@;;; 
@;;; Here we can add numerous cases for different date formats.
@;;;
@  (try)
@    (cases)
\@hh:@mm:@ss @year/@mo/@da\ @stuff
@    (or)
*@year.@mo.@da @hh.@mm.@ss* @stuff
@    (or)
@line
@    (throw error `line @lineno: unrecognized format`)
@    (end)
@    (filter :tonumber hh mm ss year mo da)
@    (do
       (each ((n (list hh mm ss year mo da)))
         (if (null n)
           (throw 'error `line @lineno: bad number`))
         (if (< n 0)
           (throw 'error `line @lineno: negative number`)))
       (if (> hh 23)
         (throw 'error `line @lineno: hour > 23`))
       (if (> mo 12)
         (throw 'error `line @lineno: month > 13`)))
@  (catch error (err))
@    (do (format t "~a\n" err))
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Data:

```
\28:49:25 1920/11/29\ 0.25
*1920.13.29 18.49.25* 0.25
asdf *1920.28
*-1920.11.29 18.49.25* 0.25
*1920.x3.29 18.49.25* 0.25
```

Run:

```
$ txr times.txr  times.txt  | sed -e 's/^/    /'
line 1: hour > 23
line 2: month > 13
line 3: unrecognized format
line 4: negative number
line 5: bad number
```

Shrug. Maybe this exception approach isn't such a good idea because you get at most one error report per entry. But if the erroneous entries are relatively rare, that's probably okay.