# Check if given strftime format matches a date

Tags: bash, date, awk, gawk, strftime

I have strftime format of time, let's say `(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)` and a file which should contain this kind of data e.g. `(2012-02-11 17:15:00)`. I need to check if given pattern actually matches the data. 
How to approach this? awk, date?

**EDIT:**
More info: The user enters the strftime format, let's say on input. Then he enters a file which should contain those dates. I need to make sure, that those data are valid (he didn't make a mistake). So I need to check the rows in the input file and see, if there are data that  matches the given pattern. Example:

- user enters strftime format: `(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)`

  input file: `(2012-02-11 17:15:00) long sentence`

  ***VALID***
- user enters strftime format: `Date[%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S]`

  input file: `Date-2012.02.11 17:15:00- long sentence`

  ***INVALID***

Comment: I don't understand, do you want this -  `echo "(2012-02-11 17:15:00)" | gawk '{if (NR==1) print strftime("(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)"), $0}'`

Comment: I've deleted my attempt to solve it, since it was a nonsense as I realised. I just need to check if it matches. thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [awk - checking timecode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050351/awk-checking-timecode)

Comment: indeed, looks like it is. There's a nice solution using python, but that's it

Answer (score 1):

If you allow an external helper binary, I've written [dateutils](http://github.com/hroptatyr/dateutils) to batch process date and time data.

```
dconv -q -i '(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)' <<EOF
not a match: 2012-04-10 12:00:00
a match: (2012-04-10 13:00:00)
EOF
```

will give

```
2012-04-10T13:00:00
```

`-i` is the input format, `-q` suppresses warnings.  And `dconv` tries to convert input lines to output lines (in this case it converts matching lines to ISO standard format.

So using this, a file matches completely if the number of input lines equals the number of output lines.

Comment: Unfortunatly I probably don't, since this is a homework assignment and I should use only "standard" unix programs. This is exactly what I'm trying to do though. Can't this be done using awk? Thx for answer.

Comment: the problem is that awk has no `strptime()` function, nor does perl, unfortunately (not taking CPAN extensions into account)

Comment: hm, done a lot of research and I just can't find anything. So you really think this can't be solved without C?

Comment: no, I'm not saying it can't be done, I mean it's a lot easier if awk/perl/foo had a `strptime()`, then you'd just go `strptime("(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)", $input)` and if that succeeds without error, you know the date was parsed correctly.

Comment: @hroptatyr: Perl's `Time::Piece` is a core module that provides `strptime()`. Python provides it in `time` and `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check current datetime:

```
echo "(2012-02-11 17:15:00)" | grep "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

If some other you need GNU date (-d option). This works for me:

```
echo "(2012-02-11 17:15:00)" | 
grep "$(date -d "2012-02-11 17:15:00"  "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
```

Comment: This checks only the data inside, but I need to check the parentheses as well. For example this will validate `x2012-02-11 17:15:00)` too...  Unfortunately (let's switch the parenthesis with "x") `echo "x2012-02-11 17:15:00x" |  grep "$(date -d "x2012-02-11 17:15:00x"  "+x%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%Sx")"` is not working

Comment: I would like to modify my question for better understanding, but I just don't know how.. do you know what I want to accomplish?

Comment: Well, just add parentheses in date specifier: `grep "$(date -d "2012-02-11 17:15:00"  "+(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)")"` If you need some other answer, I think input example can help.

Comment: But notice that you removed the paranthesis in -d option. And that's the problem. There can be paranthesis - which you removed - but as well `xxx` or whatever. The whatever is specified by user. I'll add some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a brute force approach to this: replace any `%X` specifier with a corresponding regular expression, then you can filter out lines that don't match the resulting generated regex:

```
user_format="%Y-%m-%d"
awk -v fmt_string="$user_format" '
  BEGIN {
    gsub(/[][(){}?|*+.]/ "\\&", fmt_string)  # protect any regex-special chars
    gsub(/%Y/, "([0-9]{4})", fmt_string)
    gsub(/%m/, "(0[1-9]|1[012])", fmt_string)
    gsub(/%d/, "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])", fmt_string)
    # and so on
  }
  $0 !~ "^" fmt_string {print "line " NR " does not match: " $0}
' filename
```

Comment: ooh, that's brutal... looks like there's nothing better though